# Sci-Fi short about people increasing appreciation for beauty too high for sanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story I read online about ten years ago about some shipmates visiting a settlement area (a planet?) that's producing beautiful art. But all the people there are apathetic about their creations. The characters marvel at the beauty but leave confused.

On the ship-ride home they realize they've been contaminated with the intoxicant that makes the settlement people yearn for beauty, but also makes them find anything less than perfection to be agonizing.

One of the shipmates locks themselves in their room and studies math theorems to stave off the madness of all the ugliness.

The main character keeps thinking about how perfect their wife is and survives by imagining how grateful they'll be when they get home to see her.

The story ends with the character seeing their wife again and noticing minor flaws in her face and hair. The main character then kills themself.

Comment: The main character is nonbinary, or you just don't remember if they were male or female? Their wife is a female?

Comment: @user14111 (Or maybe the character is known to be male, but OP used gender-neutral pronouns anyway, perhaps out of habit?)

Comment: When and where did you read this?  Was it in an anthology, a magazine, or online?

Comment: The main character is likely a man, I just don't remember. I read the story online I think about 10 years ago.